# How to reason about the complexity of my code

Tags: java

i did some coding in java to find a missing number know my code is working. i have basic knowledge about how to check the complexity of the program and  i have keen interest to learn about how can i do that please any one help me or suggest me to read some good tutorial. or help me to know somthing about asymptotic complexity related to my code. Thank You.

here is my code

```
Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter No:");
    int length=s1.nextInt();
    boolean isExit=false;
    int []a=new int[length-1];
    System.out.println("Enter all no");
    for(int i=0;i<length-1;i++){
    a[i]=s1.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i<=length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if(i==a[j]){
             isExit =true;
             break;
            }
        }
        if (!isExit) {
            System.out.println(i);
            //break;
        }
        isExit = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Please give some explanation about asymptotic complexity related to my code.

Comment: If you can ask a specific question, you might get a specific answer.  But "explain all about X" isn't really what Stack Overflow is about.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

What you are looking to learn for is called asymptotic complexity.

A good video : [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7frcB_-g4w)

Also check out this answer 
[What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

In relation to your post :

```
for (int i = 1; i<=length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if(i==a[j]){
             isExit =true;
             break;
            }
        }
        if (!isExit) {
            System.out.println(i);
            //break;
        }
        isExit = false;
    }
```

Assuming that the operations inside your inner loop take constant time O(1).

If you think about this chunk of code in terms of code complexity you can notice that the outer loop will execute **at most** N(`length`) times and you can notice that the inner loop will execute N times too.Thus at most **N^2** operations will be executed thus the upper bound of your algorithm is O(N^2) which means that the function N^2 will always be above the operations you make.

Comment: now i want to compare my both code based on efficency

Comment: @J.Kr Yes, you do that using asymptotic complexity.I will include some references for you to read in a moment.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain something about asymptotic complexity related to my code. thanks for response

Comment: I hope this will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're specifically trying to learn to do it all by hand? If not it's relatively easy to use streams to find the missing number:

```
Arrays.sort(array);
IntStream.range(0, array.length).filter(n -> !n.equals(array[n])).findAny();
```

That returns an `Optional<Integer>` which can then be tested to see if any missing number is present.